# Multiple operations/aggregations on the same Dataframe/Dataset in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.3.2.

I'm receiving data from Kafka. I must do **multiple aggregations on the same data**. Then all aggregations results will go to the **same database (columns or tables may be changed)**. For example:

```
val kafkaSource = spark.readStream.option("kafka") ...
val agg1 = kafkaSource.groupBy().agg ...
val agg2 = kafkaSource.groupBy().mapgroupswithstate() ...
val agg3 = kafkaSource.groupBy().mapgroupswithstate() ...
```

But when I try call writeStream for each aggregation result:

```
aggr1.writeStream().foreach().start()
aggr2.writeStream().foreach().start()
aggr3.writeStream().foreach().start()
```

Spark receives data independently in each writeStream. Is this way efficient?

Can I do multiple aggregations with one writeStream? If it is possible, this way is efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every “writestream” operation results in a new streaming query. Every streaming query will read from the source and execute the entire query plan. Unlike DStream, there is no cache/persist option available.

In spark 2.4, a new API “forEachBatch” has been introduced to solve these kind of scenarios in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 2):

Caching can be used to avoid multiple reads:

```
kafkaSource.writeStream.foreachBatch((df, id) => {
  df.persist()
  val agg1 = df.groupBy().agg ...
  val agg2 = df.groupBy().mapgroupswithstate() ...
  val agg3 = df.groupBy().mapgroupswithstate() ...
  df.unpersist()
}).start()
```

Comment: I use Spark 2.3.2. And It doesn't support this solution.